# Why do Mule Studio 3.4 Builds with Maven Fail or Hangs Indefinitely

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm running into the following problem attempting to build or a Mule app using Maven (using Mule 3.4).  Similarly when I update dependencies, Eclipse will hang indefinitely when trying to download com.mulesoft.licm:licm:jar:1.1.3

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mulesoft.licm:licm:jar:1.1.3: 
Could not transfer artifact com.mulesoft.licm:licm:pom:1.1.3 from/to libs-releases
(http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/repository/content/repositories/libs-releases/): 
Connection to http://dev.ee.mulesource.com refused: Connection timed out: connect 
-> [Help 1] [ERROR]
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>edu.ucdavis.edus-pub-service</groupId>
    <artifactId>edus-pub-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <mule.version>3.4.0</mule.version>
        <eclipsePluginVersion>2.8</eclipsePluginVersion>
        <jdkName>JavaSE-1.6</jdkName>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <!-- Use a newer version of the install plugin than what your Maven uses 
            by default. The older version failed to install the project if there was 
            no target/classes folder. Since we use mule packaging on the project we actually 
            create and attach the zip that must be installed. -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.6,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>attach-test-resources</goal>
                                            <goal>filter-resources      </goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${eclipsePluginVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- by default download all sources when generating project files -->
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <mainClass>org.mule.MuleServer</mainClass>
                  <arguments>
                    <argument>-config</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/app/mule-config.xml</argument>
                  </arguments>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>

              <!--Install clover-plugins-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-clover-plugins</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>

                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.cloveretl</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>cloveretl-engine</artifactId>
                                    <version>${mule.version}</version>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <!-- Using an ant task to deflate cloveretl-engine.zip -->
                                <unzip src="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/cloveretl-engine.zip" dest="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- plugins for creating site reports -->
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>http://mulesoft.org/download/attachments/92/checkstyle.xml?version=1</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>${jdk.version}</targetJdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>TODO</tag>
                        <tag>@todo</tag>
                        <tag>FIXME</tag>
                        <tag>@fixme</tag>
                        <tag>@deprecated</tag>
                    </tags>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api</link>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api</link>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api</link>
                    </links>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-beta-2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>

    <!-- UC Davis Edustream Dependencies ********************************************************************************** -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>

    </dependency> -->  

    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     -->

    <!-- UC Davis Edustream Dependencies ********************************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-boot-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-data-mapper</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-client</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-management</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-sxc</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mockobjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockobjects-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.09</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <name>JBoss</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>oss-sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus-snaphosts</id>
            <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus-releases</id>
            <name>CodeHaus Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>mulesoft-release</id>
          <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: This issue is known and being tracked by Mulesoft in the following Jira ticket:

http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-3180

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few of the MuleSoft POMs have references to their internal artifact repository which is not intended for public use. I believe it would be more responsible of them to use a profile for this or to use their own settings.xml to include this repository.

There are a number of ways to work around it. One solution is to mirror it to the public repository in your ~/.settings.xml:

```
    <mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>mule-ee-proxy</id>
        <name>Hack to not use dev.ee.mulesource.com</name>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <mirrorOf>mule-ee-releases,mule-ee-snapshots,libs-releases,ext-releases</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

It's not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 4):

I used Mule Studio 3.5.0 and experienced the same issue.

As default, Mule Studio only has EE runtime and all the tutorials shows EE runtime when you create new project. So, I needed hours and hours to find this solution

1. [Help] -> [Install new software]
2. Select [Work with] "Mule ESB Runtimes for Studio - http://studio.mulesoft.org/runtimes/"
3. Choose "Mule ESB Server Runtime 3.4.0 CE"
4. Then when you create a new Mule Project with Maven, you can see "Mule Server 3.4.0 CE Runtime"

and then, the pom.xml doesn't contain any EE dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dependency that is in the Maven repository of Mule Enterprise Edition.

In your case, I think the following EE dependencies are causing the issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-boot-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I don't think i actually have anything in my app that depends on EE, but is this calculated automatically somehow?   `SIDENOTE:  I expect we will be licensing EE soon, and will begin experimenting with EE features.`

Comment: Is the build failing because I have not entered an EE license?  If that is the case, I thought I was working with a valid evaluation license...

Comment: No the build is failing because a dependency in your project's POM depends from the EE repo. Do you depend on any EE connector? Can you share your POM?

Comment: I don't believe that my project depends on any EE connectors. I've included my pom.xml in the original post.

Comment: I've removed the boot-ee and core-ee references. Now when I attempt to build the project, it hangs indefinitely on the following step.

`Downloading: https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml`

Comment: Strange. I get an immediate `404` when `curl`ing this URL. Do you get the same?

Comment: Even stranger then :'( Maven shouldn't block on this download. Sorry I don't understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is the same problem I've been having, and that's that `http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/` is really slow.

It looks like you're trying to download the artifact for the first time in your build, and the  Mule site at times can take a while, hence your error message `Connection timed out: connect`

Answer (score 0):

There is a good discussion about this topic [here](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/why_do_mule_studio_3_4_builds_with_maven_fail_or_hangs_indefinitely)

In my case, removing the following dependencies made the trick:

- mule-module-boot-ee
- mule-core-ee
- mule-module-spring-config-ee

Those are for the Enterprise version. If you have the enterprise version and you need them as dependencies for some reason, then you first need to run the script populate_m2_repo.groovy that comes with the Enterprise version.